# How to redirect?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

what if i have 2000 links on my site, should i write mod rewrite rules for each of them
i want only 1 rule
If I use an internal rewrite rule to change my web page names instead of a redirect,it appears that I will have a duplication of content? For example, if I rewrite /oldpage.html to /working-person.html, it gets an internal redirect to working-person.html. This actually works. But oldpage.html is still a "direct" link, and does not show a 301.

The server throws a 500 error if I add [R] or [R=301] at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage.html$ working-person.html [R=301].
```

On the other hand...

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.example.com/working-person.html
```

...works. Should I just use a redirect?

I thought I read somewhere to use rewriterule instead of redirect when using other directives. Why use an internal rewrite if you get duplicate content?

Thanks for any ideas/opinions.

Answer (score 1):

This line of yours has a syntax error:

```
RewriteRule ^oldpage.html$ working-person.html [R=301].
```

There a dot in the end causing 500 internal error.

Change that to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^oldpage\.html$ /working-person.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

If you have 2000 odd links then provide some sample of old and new links so that I can suggest whether that can be handled by few mod_rewrite rules or not.

Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled through `httpd.conf` and then above code is placed in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `301` (moved **permanently**) so search engines (like Google) can reindex your site. Once that has happened you don't need the redirect anymore.

You should never have duplicate content.